# Write dynamically sized composite type datasets with HDF5 C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, dynamic-arrays, hdf5

I'm attempting to write a dynamically allocated struct into an HDF5 composite dataset, similar to [this example](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/c++/examples/compound.cpp). I have posted the relevant snippets from my code, which compiles and is surrounded by other working H5 code that writes other data structures without issue (scalars, arrays, attributes). Also, I'm *not* a C++ pro, so any let me know if anything is out of place.

First, I have a dynamically allocated `op` array of length `nop` determined at runtime:

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"

int main ()
{
    unsigned int nop = 0;
    typedef struct op_t {
        int id;
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    } op_t;
    /* there's a for-loop that determines value of nop, e.g. 1 */
    nop = 1;
    op_t *op = new op_t[nop];
    // populate with example data
    for (int n = 0; n < nop; n++)
    {
        op[n].id = n + 1;
        op[n].x = 10.0 * n + 10.0;
        op[n].y = 200.0 * n + 20.0;
        op[n].z = 30.0 * n + 30.0;
    }
```

One of my concerns is that `op` is not contiguous, but I'm not sure. Now the HDF5 part:

```
    // Move data to HDF5 composite data structure
    H5::H5File h5file ("myfile.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    H5::Group root = h5file.openGroup("/");

    hsize_t op_dim[] = {nop};
    H5::DataSpace op_dataspace(1, op_dim);

    H5::CompType op_type(sizeof(op_t));
    op_type.insertMember("id", HOFFSET(op_t, id), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
    op_type.insertMember("x", HOFFSET(op_t, x), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    op_type.insertMember("y", HOFFSET(op_t, y), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
    op_type.insertMember("z", HOFFSET(op_t, z), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);

    H5::DataSet op_ds = root.createDataSet("obs_point", op_type, op_dataspace);
    op_ds.write(op, op_type);
    op_ds.close();
    delete [] op;

    h5file.flush(H5F_SCOPE_GLOBAL);
    h5file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My resulting table is not what I expect since (1): has wrong data values, (2) header names are not correct. For example, with `nop == 1`, I see:

[image: bad1]

How did `È` get in the header names? The header names appear to change to other garbage characters every once in a while with minor changes to the code. Furthermore, the data structs were not copied or written to the HDF5 dataset.

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express with a precompiled HDF5 1.8.11 shared library which has been working fantastic with this project, except for creating/writing `H5::CompType`.

---

**UPDATE 1** This short example annoyingly works on Debian with `h5c++`, so it might be something to do with MS Visual C++.

**UPDATE 2** The problem only happens with a Debug build target, and only for `H5::CompType`. The problem "goes away" with a Release build target, which I find bizarre and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this exact problem today. Looking at the code for the CompData.insertMember isn't helpful. It really is just a thin wrapper to H5Tinsert, however I suspect that there is some suspicious behavior regarding H5std_string (which is typedef'd to std::string).

The following does not work, and returns an error that one of my member names are not unique:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t data1;
  uint32_t test;
} simple_s;
CompType mydata(sizeof(simple_s));
mydata.insertMember(name1, HOFFSET(simple_s, data1), PredType::NATIVE_UINT32);
mydata.insertMember(name2, HOFFSET(simple_s, test), PredType::NATIVE_UINT32);
```

However, if I change to use

```
H5Tinsert(mydata.getId(), "data1", HOFFSET(simple_s, data1), H5T_NATIVE_UINT32);
H5Tinsert(mydata.getId(), "test", HOFFSET(simple_s, test), H5T_NATIVE_UINT32);
```

instead of insertMember it works as expected. Alternatively this also works,

```
const H5std_string name1("data1");
const H5std_string name2("test");
mydata.insertMember(name1, HOFFSET(simple_s, data1), PredType::NATIVE_UINT32);
mydata.insertMember(name2, HOFFSET(simple_s, test), PredType::NATIVE_UINT32);
```

So it only seems to be when you pass raw cstrings to get converted. Really frustrating, even static_casting via static_cast("data1") doesn't work. I'm compiling in debug mode on VS2013 32bit and I compiled HDF5 myself using the same compiler. There are debug flags set that get turned off for std::string which is my only explanation, but I don't understand how it's interfering.

Comment: I didn't pay attention before reading this post, but we are also using H5Tinsert() directly, even though we use the C++ H5:: API generally, so it's likely the same issue.